# Joomla: Create a module that spans several positions

Tags: layout, joomla, module, html

My website at sabraso.be currently displays several modules, a bit like:

```
[::MODULE 1::][::MODULE 2::][::MODULE 3::][::MODULE 4::]
[::MODULE 1::][::MODULE 2::][::MODULE 3::][::MODULE 4::]
```

However, I want to change this layout so Module 2, which contains a landscape-format image, spans the positions 2 and 3. Afterwards, Module 3 should also be stretched to the width of Module 2 and be positioned right underneath it. Like this:

```
[::MODULE 1::][::::::::::MODULE 2::::::::][::MODULE 4::]
[::MODULE 1::][::::::::::MODULE 3::::::::][::MODULE 4::]
```

Where should I start doing this, before I actually go dig in the template files? I have noticed that some modules automatically stretch to fill the remaining space, but I cannot seem to find when and under which conditions this happens.

Now I've read one answer on Stackoverflow, but I'm not quite sure what to do with it.

Comment: To be honest, your best bet will be to make a backup of the current template you're using and start messing around with the CSS and HTML. It's hard to tell what exactly needs to be done without access to the actual template

Comment: It's hard to tell as I don't know which template you're using

Comment: I'm sorry. I'm using Gavik Postnote gk_postnote

Comment: is this a commercial template?

Comment: yes it is. I inherited this website from a previous website builder. I could edit the HTML/CSS but I'm not sure where to look.

Comment: having just looked at the GavikPro website, this template is commercial. You are very unlikely going to get support regarding this issue as people are not going to pay for the template just to help someone. I think you should download Firebug or use Chrome Dev Tools, inspect the element, find the CSS file that it's showing and go on from there. I too have had the same problem, where I don't know where to look, but I spent time looking through the files I thought were related and finally solved my problem.

Comment: I would never expect people to pay to help me :) Thanks, I'll try your suggestion. I just thought there might be a universal Joomla approach to tackling this problem.

Comment: unfortunately as Joomla is rather big, it takes mainly common sense or tools such as Firebug. Good luck with the search and I hope you get a proper answer from someone who has the template ;)